# C++ Calling non-static variable from static function windows CreateThread example

Tags: c++, static

I'm using Windows' `CreateThread` function calling it from static function. 
I want to pass to my working thread function pointer, which is a non-static member. Can it be done ?

*Header:*

```
public:
WinService();
virtual ~WinService();
private:
static DWORD WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam);
static VOID WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv);
IHttpServer* p_IHttpServer;
```

*Implementation:*

```
WinService::WinService()
{

    p_IHttpServer = new WinHttpServer();
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY [] =
    {
        { SERVICE_NAME, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain },
        { NULL, NULL }
    };

   StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable 
}
VOID WINAPI WinService::ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv)
{
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ServiceWorkerThread,  WinService::p_IHttpServer, 0, NULL); //THIS IS ERROR !!!!!
}

DWORD WINAPI WinService::ServiceWorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{

    IHttpServer* httpServer = (IHttpServer*)lpParam;


    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm getting the error in `CreateThread`, is there any way to use non-static `p_IHttpServer` there?

Comment: Why not use the standard library's threads?

Comment: this is part of legacy app , i can't change it

Comment: Well you need an instance of the `WinService` class in order to access an instance variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372967/how-do-you-use-createthread-for-functions-which-are-class-members

Comment: nice! using this and memeber from it